# number of occurences of a word in a part of file in vim

Tags: search, vim

Suppose I would like to find the number of occurrences of the word 'asd' in a part of file, eg., from line 21 to line 234. How would I do that in VIM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for counting
`:21,234s/asd//gn`

**Edit**

Since your vim is so old, try greping and count like

`sed -n 21,234p filename | grep -o asd | wc -l`

Comment: are you adding a `/` at the end? I've just tested and it is working, make sure you are copying it the exact way

Comment: I am not sure why but giving //gn in the end as mentioned is giving that error! I have tried :21,234s/asd/&/g or :21,234s/asd/asd/g and they are giving the correct count though the file will be shown as modified. I am using vim 6.3 version.

Comment: cant help! its the version installed in my company servers!! thanks for the help :)