# How to count the number of times a particular phrase has occured in gvim editor

Tags: vi

How can I count the number of times the following phrase:

`Bitwidth differs`

occurs in a test using gvim editor.

Comment: covered here yesterday in fact: [number of occurences of a word in a part of file in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985377/number-of-occurences-of-a-word-in-a-part-of-file-in-vim)

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this helps http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern